# livecd won't boot 11.04

Tags: 11.04, live-cd, boot-failure

I bought a brand new computer yesterday (Toshiba Satellite Pro L770-10T : Intel Core i5 2410M, 2,3 GHz, 4096 Mo RAM, nVidia GeForce GT 525M) that simply won't boot any livecd I tried.
I am using debian/ubuntu for a long time but this is the first time I can't boot a livecd

Here is what I tried without success: 
Ubuntu 11.04 i386 and x64 both desktop and alternate
Debian stable livecd
old working ubuntu livecds including 8.x 9.x 10.x

On ubuntu-10.04.2-desktop-i386.iso I had a kernel panic
On 11.04 packages were corrupted although md5 and sha1 were correct

I must add that those were burned on different cds CD-R or CD-RW.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you burn the CD at the slowest speed?

Comment: Have you tried booting from a LiveUSB?

Comment: Additionally, you say this is a brand-new computer you are trying to boot these on. Is there a way you can verify that the CD drive itself is not defective? That could be covered under warranty.

Comment: @scouser73 all my tries where at 4x or 8x depending on the cd. I even tried an official ubuntu cd I had.

Comment: @WarriorIng64 I didn't try liveusb but I tried debian netinstall which worked great. I had to stop it before the end because it was taking too loog, but I had no problem with it. I also thought that maybe the cd drive was itself damaged, but before messing with ubuntu I burned the windows recover dvds, and used them this morning to test them. I had no problem to get a working windows back. Would it be possible that only the cd read/write part of the optical drive is damaged? (as dvd read/write seems to work)  Thanks for your quick answers

Comment: UPDATE: I tried the usb boot and it hangs too !  This time it is on the busybox: "(initramfs) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system"

Comment: Have you altered the settings in BIOS so that when you boot from the CD that the CD drive is the first to be checked? This is commonly overlooked, and I myself have experienced it.

Comment: @scouser73 yes of course. I may not had make myself clear enough. I am booting on the livecd, but It won't go all the way until gnome launches. It stops in-between.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried adding the noacpi option and it successfully booted the livecd / liveusb

Comment: This isn't Ubuntu Forums, you've to select one of the answers using the check mark to indicate the answer solved the problem.

Comment: When you answer your own question, you have to wait 2 or 3 days to select your answer as *the* answer, so user20006 won't be able to truly close this for another couple days.